# Mac OS X Lion: folders and files permissions

Tags: macos

Every time I try to change the name of file or folder, or delete file or folder, the password dialog input appears. This is on Sites folder, permissions are drw--rw, user and everyone. The permissions of enclosed files are: everyone -> custom, user -> read&write and everyone ->read&write. I don't understand why everyone appears twice. Does anybody have an idea about what is happening?

```
drwx---rwx+ 12 alv  wheel    408 Mar  7 14:52 css
-rwx---rw-@  1 alv  wheel   1126 Mar 15 09:51 do.php
drwx---rwx+ 10 alv  wheel    340 Jan  2 02:43 images
drwx---rwx+  5 alv  wheel    170 Mar  5 15:14 includes
-rwx---rw-@  1 alv  wheel   5912 Mar 28 10:04 index.php
drwx---rwx+ 15 alv  wheel    510 Mar  7 14:52 js
drwx---rwx+  8 alv  wheel    272 Jan 30 09:55 load
-rwx---rw-@  1 alv  wheel    173 Jan 29 15:28 logout.php
-rwx---rw-@  1 alv  wheel   1630 Mar 28 16:06 map.php
drwx---rwx+ 19 alv  wheel    646 Mar 17 17:56 model
-rwx---rw-@  1 alv  wheel    309 Mar 19 13:54 robots.txt
drwx---rwx+  7 alv  wheel    238 Mar  7 10:54 shared
drwx---rwx+  3 alv  wheel    102 Mar 21 17:00 sitemap
drwx---rwx+ 17 alv  wheel    578 Mar 24 02:47 utility
-rwx---rw-@  1 alv  wheel    994 Mar 18 01:23 visitor.php
```

I think I know whats the problem. But I don't know how to fix it. Look, if I use ls -le@a:

```
-rw-r--r--@  1 alv  wheel  1839 Mar 29 18:00 header.php
    com.macromates.caret      35 
-rwxr--r--@  1 alv  wheel  2160 Mar 28 19:27 header2.php
    com.macromates.caret      35 
    0: group:everyone deny delete
```

header.php is a file I created with textmate.app. header2.php I created long ago...but I don't know when permissions changed.

How can I modify this part "0: group:everyone deny delete"?

Comment: Go to Terminal, run `ls -la ~/Sites` and post the result.

Comment: Ok, i don't know what id the wheel group

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it. It's simple. I needed to remove the `ACL 0: group:everyone deny delete`.

With this simple line, applying recursive folder and files:

`chmod -R -a# 0 Sites`

I found all that info [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/chmod.1.html)

Answer (score 1):

From your description, it sounds like you aren't the owner of the **Directory**. Click on the actual Sites directory in your home folder, hit CMD-I, and check the owner here. If it isn't you, remedy that.

Comment: I did it, didn't work.